# Segmentation fault (core dumped) with weird problems

Tags: c, cs50

The code works for small numbers but for some reason, when I put in big numbers and start the program, then write a name 2 times first time the program adds one but the second time the program adds nothing and tells me "invalid name" and for big numbers when I start writing other names it gives me "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);
int largest(int list[], int n);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        vote(name);
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) != 0)
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string NAME)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(NAME, candidates[i].name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    int Votes_here[candidate_count];

    for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
    {
        Votes_here[j] = candidates[j].votes;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes == largest(Votes_here, candidate_count))
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
        }
    }

    return;
}

int largest(int list[], int n)
{
   int i;
   int l = list[0];
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
   {
       if (list[i] > l)
           l = list[i];
   }

   return l;

}
```

I am expecting that the program count the votes and return the winner who has the most votes

Comment: Is this the CS50 Runoff problem? If you're doing CS50 problems, add the `cs50` tag.

Comment: 1. Did you compile with warnings enabled? You should always do this as it catches so many errors. (With gcc or clang, I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. 2. Running a build compiled with `-g -fsanitize=address` will help debug seg faults.

Comment: This is the problem: `strcmp(name, candidates[i].name)`. `i` is the current voter number, it has nothing to do with the candidate array. If there are more voters than candidates, you'll access outside the array.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)` - you are looping over the voters, but using `i` to index candidates.

Comment: When asking for debugging help, include an exact copy of input that reproduces the problem (the simplest input you can find that reproduces the problem), an exact copy of the observed output, and a copy of the desired output.

Comment: @ikegami why -pedantic? What is the reason of using 40-year-old ANSI  C?

Comment: @0___________, What doe ANSI C have to do with anything? -pendantic warns when you use gcc extensions, and warns when mandated by the ISO C standard. It uses the standard you specify with `-std`. 40 years old? No. You could even use it to properly follow the yet-unreleased C23. [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using the variable `i` that counts voters as the index into the `candidates` array. You'll access outside the array if there are more voters than candidates. And even when you don't go outside the array, the comparison `strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) != 0` is meaningless -- why should the i'th voter vote for the i'th candidate?

The `vote()` function should return an indicator for whether the candidate was found. You can then check that in your `if` statement.

```
    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

...
// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string NAME)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count ;i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(NAME, candidates[i].name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true; // vote is valid
        }
    }
    return false; // NAME was not found, vote is invalid
}
```